# Can I reference other objects in Firebase like in MongoDB?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a web app I developed and am working on a mobile version. I am considering dropping heroku and mlab to host on google firebase.

In my event model, I reference both the user model and the comment model. I'm wondering if this is something you can do in Firebase, or if I'd just have to completely restructure my data.

As I begin to work on a mobile version of a web app I made, I am considering the switch from heroku/mlab to hosting with google firebase. 
I have some data models that reference each other and I’m wondering if this can be done in Firebase or if I’d have to restructure my data. For example

```
let eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: {type: String, required: true},
 loc: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere', required: true},
 eventAddress: { type: String, required: true},
 city:{ type: String, required: true},
 state:{ type: String, required: true},
 dateTime: {type: Date, required: true},
 dateCreated: {type: Number},
 eventCreator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
 attending: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
 comments: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' } ]
});
```

As you can see, the last three properties are referencing the User and Comment models.